# How do I send a message to a specific User

Tags: discussion

How do I send a message to a particular user for clarification of a specific post?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is **You can't**.  But:

If you whant to add attention on the specific post, write comment with **@username** text inside, and  user will get a notification about your comment.

If user place links to Twitter, Github, and their personal website, you can check out these links, and often can see email addresses. Also, many users place their emails and Linked In profile links in their publicly available "About Me" section, especially if they are interested in networking

This question opened many times in meta stackexchange.com:

[Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

[How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

Comment: Hello @zeffii, forgive me if I steal some attention from you.
I'm a chess enthusiast, I modeled a chessboard and (not knowing Python) I embarked on writing a program that reads a game from a PGN file and, controlled by a Tkinter interface via the Forward, Back buttons etc., should make moves on the chessboard. The program is only sketched out, and I found out only now that the moves are executed, but the 3D view updates only when the script ends.
I have looked for solutions on the web and none seem to work.

Comment: Hello @zeffii, I tried to implement the brilliant solution you proposed in the script of the page "https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28673/update-viewport-while-running-script" but given my poor python knowledge I could not get any results!
If I sent you the Blender file and the script, would you have the chance to give it a look?
Thank you and excuse me for the length of the message.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: @Ave you have to do it on the question or answer that you want to reach the author.

Comment: @Ave I suggest you ask a new question about the problem you ran into (there are plenty of python people around who may be able to help, even if you don't reach zeffii). Plus, by asking that question, you may get enough upvotes to have the required reputation to post comments on the main site (and therefore be able to comment on zeffii's answer directly).

Comment: @Ave you might want to read [How do comment @ replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/278094). The only person that got pinged from your two comments there, was Crantisz.